# Graphing in Pandas matplotlib Error

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to graph this excel file. However, when I use the graphing function i keep getting an attributeError. I have already previously imported Pandas but I am still not sure why this keeps appearing:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'plt'

df1 made previously to open a file in pandas, that part of the code works well. 
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname=None)

```
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    lineplot = df1.plt(title="Dosage ",legend=None)
    fig = lineplot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig("Random Graph")
```

Comment: pyplot.plot() is used to visualise data from a data frame therefore your code should be `df1.plot(title="Dosage ",legend=None)`. Make sure that the input data is correct though - apparently you're trying to plot a dictionary, not a data frame.

Comment: Maybe just a typo - it should be `df1.plot`, not `df1.plt`.

Comment: thank you but it still gives the same error

Comment: What is the output of `df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname=None)`? Try `df1.head()`

Comment: {'Sheet1':    Dox Dossage  MiaPaCa-2
0            1          7
1            5         35
2           10         70
3          100        700
4          500       3500
5         1000       7000}

Comment: Get rid of sheetname = None and try again.

Comment: From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) : 
None -> All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames

Comment: thank u but I am still getting the same error for "no attribute called plt"

Comment: Look at the answers above - make sure you call **plot**, not **plt** on df1 and that your df1 is a data frame.

Comment: awesome it worked like a charm thank you!